# atomicAdd() showing error: no instance of overloaded function "atomicAdd" mathes the argument list

Tags: c++, matrix, vector, cuda, matrix-multiplication

So, I have to profile this matrix-vector multiplication using shared memory with CUDA, however, I am having problems to execute the code on Visual Studio 2022, I am getting the error "no instance of overloaded function "atomicAdd" mathes the argument list".

Any ideas about what it does mean and how to solve it? I would appreciate it a lot.

```
#ifndef __CUDACC__  
#define __CUDACC__
#endif
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <cuda_runtime.h>
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"
#include <cuda.h>
#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include <iostream>

#define TILE_SIZE 16
#define BLOCK_SIZE 256

__global__ void matvec(double* A, double* B, double* C, int n)
{
    __shared__ double s_A[TILE_SIZE][TILE_SIZE];
    __shared__ double s_B[TILE_SIZE];

    int bx = blockIdx.x;
    int tx = threadIdx.x;
    int i = bx * blockDim.x + tx;

    if (i < n) {
        s_B[tx] = B[i];
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j += TILE_SIZE) {
            s_A[tx][j + threadIdx.y] = A[(i * n) + j + threadIdx.y];
        }
    }
    __syncthreads();

    if (i < n) {
        double tmp = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < n; j += TILE_SIZE) {
            tmp += s_A[threadIdx.x][j + threadIdx.y] * s_B[j + threadIdx.y];
        }
        atomicAdd(&C[i], tmp);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int n = 5000;
    double* A, * B, * C;
    double* d_A, * d_B, * d_C;

    A = (double*)malloc(n * n * sizeof(double));
    B = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    C = (double*)malloc(n * sizeof(double));

    for (int i = 0; i < n * n; i++) {
        A[i] = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        B[i] = rand() / (double)RAND_MAX;
        C[i] = 0.0;
    }

    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_A, n * n * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_B, n * sizeof(double));
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_C, n * sizeof(double));

    cudaMemcpy(d_A, A, n * n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_B, B, n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_C, C, n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    dim3 dimBlock(TILE_SIZE, BLOCK_SIZE / TILE_SIZE, 1);
    dim3 dimGrid((n + BLOCK_SIZE - 1) / BLOCK_SIZE, 1, 1);

    matvec << <dimGrid, dimBlock >> > (d_A, d_B, d_C, n);

    cudaMemcpy(C, d_C, n * sizeof(double), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    cudaFree(d_A);
    cudaFree(d_B);
    cudaFree(d_C);

    free(A);
    free(B);
    free(C);

    return 0;
}
```

[image: See here the complete error from Visual Studio 2022]

Comment: Is it [this](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/#atomicadd)? In which namespace is it? Perhaps it's in `cuda::thread_scope_system`, `cuda::thread_scope_device` or `cuda::thread_scope_block`? You haven't shown what namespace you expect it to be in.

Answer (score 1):

`atomicAdd` for `double` is not available on devices with compute capability 5.0.

If you have a 6.x (Pascal) or later device, you need to tell the compiler to compile for a specific architecture as the default target architecture might still be below 6.0 and therefore the compiler wont see the definition. The easiest way of doing so is adding e.g. `-arch=sm_60` to the `nvcc` command.

In case you need this feature on an older device, the [programming guide](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomic-functions) shows how to use atomicCAS to implement it yourself.

```
#if __CUDA_ARCH__ < 600
__device__ double atomicAdd(double* address, double val)
{
    unsigned long long int* address_as_ull =
                              (unsigned long long int*)address;
    unsigned long long int old = *address_as_ull, assumed;

    do {
        assumed = old;
        old = atomicCAS(address_as_ull, assumed,
                        __double_as_longlong(val +
                               __longlong_as_double(assumed)));

    // Note: uses integer comparison to avoid hang in case of NaN (since NaN != NaN)
    } while (assumed != old);

    return __longlong_as_double(old);
}
#endif
```